# Como fazer um insert nessa tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Eu tenho um cadastro de veículos, que tem um combo box com os anos para o usuário escolher, esses anos vem da tabela "ano". Quando eu completo um cadastro de um carro novo, eu tenho que da um insert na tabela "carro", o meu problema esta ai, como vou salvar o ano que o usuário escolheu, se a tabela "carro" não tem esse campo?
[image: Tabela]

Comment: Em uma relação 1 para muitos, como você definiu entre Carro/Veículo e Veículo/Ano, você precisará armazenar o `id` de uma tabela como chave estrangeira na outra. No caso, o `id` da tabela 1 como chave estrangeira na tabela de muitos.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu estou aprendendo ainda, poderia dar o exemplo com as tabelas que eu tenho?

Comment: Tem como detalhar o que seria a tabela veículo? Não ficou muito claro para mim a diferença dela para carro.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Claro, ela surgiu por causa da Cardinalidade (0,N), pelo que eu vi na aula essa tabela Veiculo, ela só recebe chave estrangeira. Se ficar alguma dúvida, eu tento um outro exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Acho melhor nao colocar ano dentro de tabelas deixe apenas direto na combobox 
o ano-fabricacao/modelo você coloca na tabela veiculo.
tenta fazer assim:  http://www.luis.blog.br/userfiles/image/exemplo_SQL_2.jpg

Comment: Certo,vou tentar. Mas se eu tentar fazer uma busca só pelo ano, eu consigo?

Comment: sim consegue...